# Generate terminal-sigma-algebra to use Komologorov 0-1 law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

$(X_n)$ is a sequence of independent $\mathbb{R}$-random variable on ($\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$

$A:=${$\exists{N}\in\mathbb{N}$ with $X_n=X_{n+2}$ for all $n\ge$$N$}

a)Prove: $\mathbb{P}($A$)\in${0,1}

b)assume that $X_n$ are i.i.d. and $X_1$ is not a.s constant. Prove: $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$

In order to prove a), uses kolmogorov 0-1 law, so we have to define a right **terminal-$\sigma$-algebra**.

My opinion is $\mathscr{T}:=$$\bigcap_{N,I\subseteq{N}finite}$$\sigma$($X_i,i\in{N}\setminus{I}$).

```
    How can i show set A is in this sigma-algebra by using union and intersection correctly?
```

and i need some ansatz for b).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question how to show that $\mathscr J$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?  Or that $\mathscr J$ is the correct $\sigma$-algebra to use Kolmogorov 0-1 law?

Comment: @user6247850, the latter.   My idea was. $A=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{n\ge{N}}${$X_n=X_{n+2}$}  How can I state it is in $\mathscr{F}$

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you mean by defining "the right terminal $\sigma$-Algebra". There is just one, and it is clearly defined to the best of my knowledge. You can write
$$\{ X_n = X_{n+2} \forall n \geq N \text{ for some N} \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{ \bigcup\limits_{n = 1} ^\infty \bigcap\limits_{m = n} ^\infty X_m = X_{m+2}  \} = *$$
The idea behind the terminal $\sigma$-field is that it does not depend on the first $m$ random variables. In fact,

$$* =  \{ \bigcup\limits_{n = a} ^\infty \bigcap\limits_{m = n} ^\infty 
X_m = X_{m+2}  \} $$
for some $a \in \mathbb{N} $, since the intersection is increasing in $n$.    This shows the first claim.

For b, you can try to use a Borel-Cantelli argument. Clearly this set is given by $\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\{X_n = X_{n+2}\}$. Can you work out the remaining part?

Comment: +1, nice answer

Comment: thanks, your * is exactly what i had, my problem was lack of the proof that $X_m=X_{m+2}$ is in that terminal-sigmal-Algebra.

Comment: ok, i will try with Borel-Cantelli. Show that the sum of $\mathscr{P}(X_n=X_{n+2})\lt\infty$

Comment: Hi, do I have to prove $\sum_{n\ge{1}} \mathscr{P}$(inf{$X_n=X_{n=2}$})$\lt\infty$, is my formatting right?

Comment: Im not quite sure what this expression is supposed to be, but it looks quite wrong. You can use the hint I gave, look at the complement set and use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma together with the assumption that X_n isn't constant a.s..

Comment: Hi. Use your hint with Borel-Cantelli and we got $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(A^{c})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(X_n\neq{X_{n+2}})\lt\infty\implies\mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}infA_n)=1\implies\mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}supA_n)=0$.  Is that right?

Comment: No, and besides, what you wrote here is the exact opposite of what you actually wanted to prove.